# How is variable declaration happening in javascript?

Tags: javascript

```
console.log(x)
var x = 10;
```

The console gives me undefined but I was expected reference error

Comment: That's how `var` works - it has range of quirks like this. `let` and `const` fix these, with them, you'd get the error you expect.

Comment: See e.g. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting. Unlike `let`, `var` has no _temporal dead zone_.

Comment: Please see [Are variables declared with let or const hoisted?](/q/31219420/4642212), [What is the temporal dead zone?](/q/33198849/4642212), [Javascript function scoping and hoisting](/q/7506844/4642212).

Answer (score 2):

`var` is the old way of declaring a variable in JS. It has a few properties that you should consider in comparison to what `let` and `const` let you do.

Your variable declaration `var x = 10` will be raised up to the top of the script, as a function declaration on the other hand is hoisted by the JS engine during compilation. However, ONLY the declaration is hoisted and the variable will be assigned `undefined` until you assign to it another value manually using the assignment operator `=`.

JS engine doesn't throw a `ReferenceError` because your code is translated (using hoisting) into

```
var x;
console.log(x);
x = 10;
```

At the same time, `var` doesn't have the concept of block scope, so at the same time the code below is running just fine

```
console.log(x);
{
  var x = 10;
}
```

The code above is being translated (using hoisting) into

```
var x;
console.log(x);
{
  x = 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If a variable is used in code and then declared and initialized, the value when it is used will be its default initialization (`undefined` for a variable declared using var, use `const` and `let` to avoid this).